# Visual Studio 2022 - Taking notes (Not in code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

There is any way to take notes in the code without put a comment?

I know some tips, like:

- Add breakpoints and put labels; then I can open the breakpoint window and I will see specific lines:
  [image]
- Or, add bookmarks and navigate with the shortcuts.

But, there is any other strategy to put comments or take notes without putting comments in the code?

Why? - Basically because sometimes I like to put my own comments, and I work with a large group of devs; so I don't want to push those notes into the repo (or even go to clean the code before making a commit).

Comment: Probably noy what you want: There is the 'ToDo'  system. If it's just temporary notes to yourself, you can use something 'Sticky notes'.

Comment: I've never tried this, but... https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DaleCover.code-annotator.  <quote> Code Annotator lets you keep notes about your code without adding TODOs and comments in your code directly. Your annotations are stored inside of the IDE and displayed in the sidebar for easy reference.</quote>

Comment: @Flydog57 extension you shared only for VSCode not Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

Its either executable code or its a (single `//` or multi-line `/* */` ) comment in .net

Either you look into setting up git to ignore your specific lines you don't want to include, which to be honest doesn't look like something that is worth the time investment, or use a note taking application that allows you to include code snippets. Then just keep your notes open. This is what I do for personal notes and comments that don't need to be committed to the repo.

Personally, I like [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) and use it for all of my code notes, it uses Prism.js for rendering code snippets, though it comes with learning a bit of markdown. I use OneNote a lot as well at work, when I need a more freeform scrapbook sort of WYSIWYG interface, but that doesn't have specific functionality for code snippets.

Comment: Is not what I'm looking for. But still is a good option I will take a look of this app. Thanks for sharing!